# Gzip CSS Compression ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, gzip

Using IIS10, ASP NET MVC 5

I have enabled dynamic and static compression in IIS and installed both features from Server Maanger. I added the below to my web.config:

```
<httpCompression directory="%SystemDrive%\inetpub\temp\IIS Temporary Compressed Files">
    <scheme name="gzip" dll="%Windir%\system32\inetsrv\gzip.dll" staticCompressionLevel="9" />
    <dynamicTypes>
    <add mimeType="text/*" enabled="true" />
    <add mimeType="message/*" enabled="true" />
    <add mimeType="application/x-javascript" enabled="true" />
    <add mimeType="application/json" enabled="true" />
    <add mimeType="*/*" enabled="false" />
    </dynamicTypes>
    
    <staticTypes>
    <add mimeType="text/*" enabled="true" />
    <add mimeType="message/*" enabled="true" />
    <add mimeType="application/x-javascript" enabled="true" />
    <add mimeType="application/atom+xml" enabled="true" />
    <add mimeType="application/xaml+xml" enabled="true" />
    <add mimeType="*/*" enabled="false" />
    </staticTypes>
    
</httpCompression>
    
<urlCompression doStaticCompression="true" doDynamicCompression="true" />
```

The css files appear to be served in as gzip compressed and the Response header contains:

```
content-encoding:gzip
```

However, when rendered on the browser the css file is not being registering (ie non of the styles are being applied).

Is there a step I have missed?

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that the Dynamic content Compression feature and Static Content Compression are installed.
[image]

Comment: Yes, I installed both of these features

Comment: Try to redeploy your application on IIS:https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/asp-net-mvc5-deployment-on-windows-iis-server/